# How to show an error on pop up login page?

Tags: php, html, validation, popup

my PHP application where users have to login on a popup login page that appears after pressing a button.
**The login button is as:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-nav">
        <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" class="btn btn-blue">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**the pop up login page is as**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modal-popup">
            <a href="#" class="close-link"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
            <br />
            <h3 class="white">Sign Up</h3>
            <?php if(validation_errors()){  ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php echo form_open('verifylogin/'); ?>
                <form class="popup-form" action="">
                    <input class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus  AutoComplete=off ><br />
                    <input class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"  autocomplete=off  value="">      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When credentials fail an error message is displayed only when the user presses the sign up button again instead of own self.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code example of your html/css/js/php page in order to be helped.

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly you are looking for without an example of your current code. Maybe put it into a jsfiddle link? It sounds like you want to have an error show up when incorrect credentials are entered. You could do this with a simple

```
alert('Your error here');
```

And just run that if the login fails. You can even get fancy and put the username the user typed in as such

```
alert('Wrong password for '+ u_name +'. Please try again');
```

There are other ways to produce errors but it seems like you're looking for something simple and quick.